# Deserialize XML by converting it to json string

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I want to deserialize the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Jobs>
   <Job>
      <Id>1</id>
      <Description>d1</description>
   </Job>
   <Job>
      <Id>2</id>
      <Description>d2</description>
   </Job>
</Jobs>
```

- I don't want to use [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) because [it cannot set private members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429380/using-xmlserializer-with-private-and-public-const-properties).
- I don't want to use [DataContractSerialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=net-6.0) because (**I believe**) [elements order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943176/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-datacontractserializer). my xml document comes from a 3rd party and elements order may change (because there may be additional elements in between)

So I tried to convert the XML to Json and deserialize the jsonstring:

```
public class Job
{
    public string Id { private get; set; }
    public string ThirdPartyId => $"third-party-id-{Id}";
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And this how I try to deserialize:

```
public List<Job> Deserialize(XDocument xDocument)
{
   string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDocument);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Job>>(jsonString);
}
```

The above fails, I believe because the json contains "xml" node...

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"utf-8"},
"Jobs":{"Job":[{"Id":"1","Description":"D1"}, {"Id":"2","Description":"D2"}]}
```

Is it possible to remove the xml node from xDocument? Is there a better option for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: XElement

```
var xmlNoRoot = XElement.Parse(youXML);
var jsonStringNoRoot = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
```

ref: https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/converting-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-using-c/347