# Serialize protected properties with XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

I would like to make 'Keys' and 'Data' protected but I think there is no way or at least not without a lot of trouble.

```
public class baseDB<T> 
{

/// <summary>
/// Should not be used... Made public for XML serializer (Should be protected)
/// Use GetKeys() instead
/// </summary>
public List<String> Keys { get;  set; }
/// <summary>
/// Should not be used... Made public for XML serializer (Should be protected)
/// Use GetData() instead
/// </summary>
public List<T> Data { get;  set; }

public List<String> GetKeys()
{
    return new List<String>(Keys);
}

public List<T> GetData()
{ 
    return new List<T>(Data); 
}
// .... rest truncated ...
```

´

Comment: There is no way to do this with `XmlSerializer` other than implementing `IXmlSerializable`, which is a pain.  See [Using XmlSerializer with private and public const properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/429380/3744182).  That question is very old, but `XmlSerializer` hasn't changed much since .NET 2.0.  `DataContractSerializer` from .NET 3 can serialize private members, but is more limited in other ways (for instance, it does not support XML attributes.)

Comment: Hmm. looks like `init` only properties do work with `XmlSerializer`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/n5hXJc.  Is that good enough for you?

Comment: I will Look into that. I don't need XML attributes here. Thank you

Comment: Oh this is interesting.  In .NET 8 (and maybe earlier?) the setter can be marked as `protected` (or even removed entirely) and serialization will work, provided the value is pre-initialized, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/QN3lq8.  I don't think that was always true.  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: You could also use a surrogate array property, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/oMC9sB.